# How would I go about changing the output of tkinters "colorchooser" module into a RGB code usable by pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have a .png image of a dice. All pixels are coloured black and I want the user to be able to change the pixel colour to a colour chosen through the tkinter colorchooser module. I am using pillow to change the colour of the image and tkinter to allow the user to choose the colour. The following code is the function I'm using.

```
def ColourCustomisation():     

     colourCode = colorchooser.askcolor(title ="Change Colour")

     importD20 = Image.open("d20.png")
     importD20 = importD20.convert("RGB")

     datas = importD20.getdata()

     new_image_data = []
     for item in datas:
         # change all pixels to input colour
         if item[0] in list(range(0, 256)):
         new_image_data.append(("colourCode"))

     # update image data
     importD20.putdata(new_image_data)

     # save new image
     importD20.save("d20.png")

 ColourButton = Button(root, text = "Colour Customisation", command = ColourCustomisation)
 ColourButton.grid(column=3, row=2)
```

The problem I run into is the format with which tkinter returns the value "colourCode". Instead of giving a RGB code it returns a RGB and Hex colour code.

For example, it returns the colour red as:

```
((255.99609375, 0.0, 0.0), '#ff0000')
```

I don't know, and cant find anything to explain how I would go about changing this output to something acceptable by pillow. I'd love some suggestions on how I can isolate the RGB code and then convert them into integers as pillow does not accept the values as floats

Comment: There is the [`ImageColor`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageColor.html) module in pillow that can do the conversion.

Comment: Doesn't pillow accept `"#ff0000"`? Also why not just use `int(<number>)` to convert the `float`s to `int`s?